# 時系列ごとにメッセージを表示する方法を教えて欲しいです。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css

課題：時系列ごとにメッセージを表示する

１対１でメッセージをやり取りするメッセージアプリをRailsで作成中です。

やりたいことは、ユーザー一覧画面でユーザーを選択して、選択したユーザーの詳細画面でメッセージ投稿して、そのユーザー詳細画面でメッセージを表示したいです。
ユーザー詳細画面で送信ユーザーと受信ユーザーがどちらもメッセージを見れるようにしたいです。（よくあるチャットアプリのようなイメージです）

配列結合でメッセージは取得できていると思うのですが、メッセージの表示をLINEのように時系列ごとに「自分の投稿メッセージを画面右」、「相手の投稿メッセージを画面左」にする方法を教えて欲しいです。

```
#コントローラー
     class UsersController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @users = User.all
      end
      
      def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @re_uname = @user.name
        @current_uname = User.find_by(name: current_user.name)
        @sent_messages = current_user.sent_messages.where(recipient_id: params[:id])
        @received_messages = @user.sent_messages.where(recipient_id: current_user.id)
    
        @messages = (@sent_messages + @received_messages).sort_by(&:created_at)
      end
    
    end

#Messageモデル
    class Message < ApplicationRecord
      belongs_to :sender, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
      belongs_to :recipient, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
    end


#Userモデル
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
            :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
    
      has_many :sent_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: 'sender_id'
      has_many :received_messages, class_name: 'Message', foreign_key: 'recipient_id'
          
    end
```

#views/users/show.html.erb

```
<h1>Users#show</h1>


#試したこと①
  <% @messages.each do |msg| %>
    <% if msg.sender_id == current_user.id %>
      <%= msg.sender_id %>
      <%= msg.recipient_id %>
      <%= msg.message %>
      <br>
      <%= msg.created_at%>
      <br>
    <% elsif msg.recipient_id == params[:id] %>
      <%= msg.message %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>


<%= link_to "トップページ", root_path %>

#試したこと②
<div class="messages">
<% @messages.each do |msg| %>
  <br>
  
  <% if @sent_messages %>
    <div class="current_user">
        <%= @current_uname.name %>
        <%= msg.sender_id %>
        <%= msg.recipient_id %>
      <div class="msg">
        <%= msg.message %>
      </div>
      <%= msg.created_at%>
    </div>
  <% elsif @received_messages %>
    <%= @re_unmae %>
    <%= msg.message %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
</div>


<h1>*******************************************</h1>
#試したこと③
<% @sent_messages.each do |msg| %>

<p style="text-align:right">
  <%= @current_uname.name %>
  <%= msg.sender_id %>
  <%= msg.recipient_id %>
  <%= msg.message %>
  <%= msg.created_at%>
</p>
<% end %>

<% @received_messages.each do |remsg| %>
<br>
  <%= @re_uname %>
  <%= remsg.sender_id %>
  <%= remsg.recipient_id %>
  <%= remsg.message %>
  <%= remsg.created_at%>

<% end %>
<h1>*******************************************</h1>
#以下はメッセージ投稿フォーム
<h2>新規投稿</h2>

<%# <%= @user_message %>

<%= form_with url: messages_path do |f| %>

  <p>message</p>
  <%= f.text_area :message, size: "50x10" %></br>
  <%= f.hidden_field :recipient_id, value: params[:id] %>



  <%= f.submit '送信'%>
<% end %>
```

コードは以上です。（不足分あれば教えてもらえますでしょうか。）
#試したこと①〜③
でメッセージは取得できていると思います。

しかし、コントローラーで@messagesを：created_atでそ並べ替えしているが、送信者、受信者ごとの時系列となり、送信者、受信者の共にcreated_atでの並べ替えがされていないように見えます。

画像は試したこと③の結果です。右がzユーザー（ログインユーザー）の全メッセージが時系列順に並んでいる。
左がaユーザー（params[:id]で詳細画面に遷移したユーザー）の全メッセージが時系列順に並んでいる。
ユーザー基準で時系列順に並んでいるのを、時系列順を基準に並べる方法を教えてもらえますでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 「左と右に寄せる」自体は出来ていて、「created_at での並び替え」が問題として残っている…ように見えます。質問のタイトルは作りたいものではなく、課題を表現した方が回答も付きやすいと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
課題をタイトルに記載しました。
タイトル：時系列ごとにメッセージを表示する方法を教えて欲しいです。